# ng$watch gets called too often and despite equality check

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 controllers defined. One creates a list and the other (nested) consumes it.
I am using $watch('listname',function,true) plus also guarding explictly against duplicates,
but (1) the watch gets hit multiple times, and (2) some times with the exact same old/new.
I am wondering what am I doing wrong.

```
myApp.controller("ovcMainCtlr", [ "$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http){
    //...
    $scope.toggleVPCSelection = function(vpc_id) {
        assert(vpc_id in $scope.gVPCList, "missing vpc_id=" + vpc_id + " in the list?");
        $scope.gVPCList[vpc_id].selected = ! $scope.gVPCList[vpc_id].selected;
        $scope.gSelectedVPCList = _.sortBy( _.pluck(_.filter( $scope.gVPCList, {selected:true} ), "id" ) );
    };
}]);
```

and the second:

```
myApp.controller("ovcServerCtlr", [ "$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http){
    //...
    $scope.$watch('gSelectedVPCList', function(newval, oldval){
        console.log("watch! new vpc sel=", newval, "old=", oldval);
        if ( newval && newval.length && ! angular.equals(newval, oldval) ) {
            _refreshServerList(newval);
        }
    }, true);
}]);
```

the HTML

```
<body ng-controller="ovcMainCtlr">
    <div class="panel">
        <span>Select VPC Filter >>></span>
        <span class="vpc-selector" ng-repeat="vpc in vpcList()">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vpc" value="vpc.id" ng-checked="vpc.selected"
                   ng-click="toggleVPCSelection(vpc.id)">
            {{ vpc.id + " / " + vpc.name }}
        </span>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div ng-repeat="vpc in gSelectedVPCList" ng-controller="ovcServerCtlr">
        I can see a selected {{ vpc | json }}
    </div>
    ...
```

The console says, as I click to modify gSelectedVPCList, and then check equals

```
  watch! new vpc sel= ["v1-123456789", "v2-4567"] old= ["v1-123456789"] serverCtlr.js:31
  watch! new vpc sel= ["v1-123456789", "v2-4567"] old= ["v1-123456789"] serverCtlr.js:31
  watch! new vpc sel= ["v1-123456789", "v2-4567"] old= ["v1-123456789", "v2-4567"] serverCtlr.js:31
> angular.equals( ["v1-123456789", "v2-4567"], ["v1-123456789", "v2-4567"] )
  true
```

Thanks.

-- EDIT, in $watch changed to `angular.equals()` instead of `!==`!! But the rest of the issue remains the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of the `$diggest` cycle.

Every time that angular enters in the `$diggest` cycle, the `$diggest` cycle will evaluate all the `$watch` functions of the `$scope`.

The `$diggest` cycle is the stage in which Angular ensures the changes of the model have settled,
so that it can render the view with the updated changes. In order to do that,
Angular starts a loop in which each iteration evaluates all the template expressions
of the view, as well as the `$watcher` functions of the `$scope`.
If in the current iteration the result is the same as the previous one,
then Angular will exit the loop. Otherwise, it will try again.
If after 10 attempts things haven't settled, Angular will exit
with an error: The ["*Infite $diggest Loop Error*" (`infdig`)](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig).

This graphic may help you understand how Angular works behind the scenes:

[image]

(I borrowed from [here](http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/01/31/banging-your-head-against-an-angularjs-issue-try-this/))

Comment: That explains, thanks a lot! So, I guess all $watch callbacks must guard for equals, irrespective of the third argument = true.

Comment: I am still concerned that the $watch gets called twice with exact same argument list. How do people work around that? Should I maintain a local copy of the watched variable?

Comment: @Dinesh the third argument `= true` is for indicating that you want angular to perform a deep `$watch`, otherwise angular will just perform a shallow `$watch`. For collections however if you don't want angular to perform a deep `$watch`, you should use [`$watchCollection`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection)

Comment: @Dinesh about that concern I have [this post in my blog](http://sobrepere.com/blog/2014/10/14/creating-groupby-filter-angularjs/) that briefly explains why the $diggest cycle always tries to evaluate everything at least twice.

Comment: @Dinesh Since my answer solves your original question I think that you should mark it as accepted, if you have further questions please post another question and I will be happy to help you there. Thanks!

Comment: nice blog. I tried with selecting 3 items in my list and indeed! the watch got called 3 times. Repeat with 4, same again. I will need to refactor. I am thinking of using emit/on signaling which should obviate the need for ngWatch...

Comment: it turned out I had used the controller multiple times in my HTML. So the constructor apparently got called multiple times, registering the watch handler (same scenario when I changed to broadcast/on method). After I removed the multiple references, the duplicated callbacks stopped. So, obviously I have some different kind of head-scratching to do.